# SQL IN-Operator: consider multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

This is my table:

```
Column1 Column2
1       A
2       B
3       B
2       C
4       B
```

I have following SQL query to get all rows with column1 matching an input list with numbers, for example "1, 2, 3":

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 IN (1, 2, 3);
```

This query is generated by a program appending every number.
Now I want all rows with column1 matching a number while matching a character of column2, e.g. "1 and A, 2 and B, 4 and B".
A possible query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE (column1 = 1 and column2 = 'A') 
     OR (column1 = 2 and column2 = 'B') 
     OR (column1 = 4 and column2 = 'B')
```

What if my list has thousand value pairs and my table several hundred of thousand entries? 
Is there a better way to get the same result or do I have to append one thousand of "OR"s?

Sadly this isn't working:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE (column1, column2) IN ((1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (4, 'B'))
```

Comment: Depends on the dbms used. The following features outside Core SQL-2003 are used: F641, "Row and table constructors"; T051, "Row types"; F561, "Full value expressions"

Comment: SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE (column1, column2) IN ((1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (4, 'B'))  should work (note the quotes), which DMBS are you on?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sybase SQL Anywhere. I didn't know this makes such a difference.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `(column1, column2) IN ((1, A), (2, B), (4, B))  ` is perfectly legal SQL (at least if you properly quote the string literals) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a0d4c/1

Comment: Are the couplets of variables dynamic or a set array ?  You could insert them into a secondary table, and join to the first.  This way you can make good usage of indexing.

Comment: Yes I used the quotes. The variables are loaded by the user and may be different each time.

Comment: Then you should create a table or a table variable with the matching index. Load the user's filters, and join to the main table.

Comment: Thanks @Amir it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do. It generally would perform better than IN with OR's and is much more readable in my opinion.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 1 AS col1, 'a' AS col2 UNION
SELECT 2, 'b' UNION
SELECT 4, 'b'
) AS tbl
ON tbl.col1=TABLE.col1 AND tbl.col2=TABLE.col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a table or a table variable with the matching index. Load the user's filters, and join to the main table.

Answer (score 1):

Well I needed something similar but for a DELETE statement where I wanted to delete rows in table A based on a filtered rows with the same primary key columns from table B. So I used string function to concate the primary key columns and than used IN. Is not the cleanest way but it helped...

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE string(PK1,'~',PK2) IN (SELECT string(PK1,'~',PK2) FROM B WHERE columnXZ = 'D')
```

That '~' is just in case...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH CTE1 AS(SELECT column1,column2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  column1  
ORDER BY   column2) AS Row_Count FROM Table_Name)
SELECT column1,column2 FROM CTE1 WHERE Row_Count = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
  SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE (column1, column2) 
    IN (
        SELECT 1 c1, 'A' c2 FROM dual
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'B' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, 'B' FROM dual
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
create  table #temp (id int, val varchar(1))
insert into #temp (id,val) values (1,'A') 
insert into #temp (id,val) values (2,'B') 
insert into #temp (id,val) values (3,'B') 
insert into #temp (id,val) values (4,'C') 
insert into #temp (id,val) values (5,'C') 


select * from #temp where val in (
select val from #temp where id in (1,2,3))
```